# Werid gray area in the buttom of the page

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

This page only contain a header there is no footer at all https://test.com/

What I'm trying to do is to make the page at full size without scrolling on mobile and on laptop.
I tried to set the high to 100%
But it doesn't work.
My whole problem from this CSS I guess

```
.custom-header-media {
    min-height: 200px;
}
```

I tried to set it as

```
height: 100%;
height: auto;
```

and still doesn't work.

Also I tried to setup the pic as:

```
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
```

And still doesn't work, I setup the the page as

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this CSS for the full-width image

```
.custom-header-media .wp-custom-header img, .custom-header-media video {
    height: 100vh;
}
.site-inner {
    overflow-x: unset;
}
```

Comment: What is the goal here to copy the answer I posted... without even explanation of the basic solution

Comment: This answer is not copied, please check here is more line of code @MaxiGui

Answer (score 1):

juust set: `height: 100vh` will fix it. as vh = viewport height.

Here an example: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_unit_vh

The grey color you are getting under is not weird, this is just the body color going until the bottom of the page.

But you might encounter other problem or responsiveness, that you should check based on the screen width.

```
.custom-header-media {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Enjoy.